# Spring JPA Table per Class only join with one specific Table

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have two inheritance structures in my Projekt. NY-Store served only NY-Pizza, Italian-Store ony Italian-Pizza.

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class PizzaStore {

   String name;
   List<Pizza> pizzas;

}

@Entity
public class NYPizzaStore extends PizzaStore {

   specific NYPizzaSore Attributes

}

@Entity
public class ItaliaPizzaStore extends PizzaStore {

   specific ItaliaPizzaSore Attributes

}

===============
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class Pizza {

   List<Ingredient> ingredients

}

@Entity
public class NYPizza extends Pizza {

   specific NYPizza Attributes

}

@Entity
public class ItalianPizza extends Pizza {

   specific ItalianPizza Attributes

}
```

OK, there are many specific stores and pizzas so JPA-Hibernate give an Error that i can't join over 60 Tables.

I change my code to

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class PizzaStore {

   String name;

}

public class NYPizzaStore extends PizzaStore {
   
   List<NYPizza> NYPizzas;
   ... specific NYPizzaSore Attributes

}

public class ItaliaPizzaStore extends PizzaStore {

   List<ItalianPizza> italianPizzas;
   ... specific ItaliaPizzaSore Attributes

}
```

Now i have the Problem that i can't iterate over my sotres and call

```
getPizza();
```

becouse i must call `getNYPizza()` or `getItalianPizza()` to the specific Store.

Is there an Option to say Hiberante ItalianSotres only join with ItalianPizza? Or should i add an abstract Methodes `getPizza()` to the Superclass Store and implement in the specific class

```
public class ItaliaPizzaStore extends PizzaStore {

   List<ItalianPizza> italianPizzas;
   ... specific ItaliaPizzaSore Attributes

   public Pizza getPizza(){
      return getItalianPizza();
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Or should i add an abstract Methodes getPizza() to the Superclass Store and implement in the specific class

That's how you can do it.